# Get auto Incremented field value in SQL Server 2008 from C# Code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

tbl_ProductCatg

```
Id    IDENTITY
Code
Description
a few more.
```

Id field is auto-incremented and I have to insert this field value in Code field.

i.e. if Id generated is 1 then in Code field the value should be inserted like 0001(formatted for having length of four),if id is 77 Code should be 0077.

For this, I made the query like:

```
insert into tbl_ProductCatg(Code,Description)
values(RIGHT('000'+ltrim(Str(SCOPE_IDENTITY()+1,4)),4),'testing')
```

This query runs well in sql server query analyzer but if I write this in C# then it insets Null in Code even Id field is updated well.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at [Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) ([Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx))

From what is sounds like you are trying to do, this would work well for you.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_ProductCatg
(
   ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
   , Code AS RIGHT('000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
   , Description NVARCHAR(128)
)
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_ProductCatg
ADD Code AS RIGHT('000' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
```

You can also make the column be `PERSISTED` so it is not calculated every time it is referenced.

Marking a column as `PERSISTED` Specifies that the Database Engine will physically store the computed values in the table, and update the values when any other columns on which the computed column depends are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SCOPE_IDENTITY isn't designed to be used during an insert so the value will not be populated until after the insert happens.

The three solutions I can see of doing this would be either making a stored procedure to generate the scope identity and then do an update of the field.

```
insert into tbl_ProductCatg(Description) values(NULL,'testing')
update tbl_ProductCatg SET code=RIGHT('000'+ltrim(Str(SCOPE_IDENTITY()+1,4)),4) WHERE id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

The second option, is taking this a step further and making this into a trigger which runs on UPDATE and INSERT. I've always been taught to avoid triggers where possible and instead do things at the SP level, but triggers are justified in some cases.

The third option is computed fields, as described by @Adam Wenger

Comment: SQL server's computed columns allows for a column to be `PERSISTED`.  This means that the value is calculated on Insert, then stored similar to a traditional column.  This eliminates the down-side of multiple computations on reads.